# how to use model binder to post data from a form + value of a span to data base

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, modelbinder

Good time. 
I'm new in Asp.net-MVC .

I have a form which it gets data from user and there is a span in this page which I want to post data of inputs and value of span to my data base.

I wanted to use model binder but I don't know how to name spans same as my model.

here is my action :

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,TourId,FirstName,LastName,Email,Phone,Comment,FrequentTraveler,TravelersCount,Date,ContactTimePreference,Country,Archived")] Request request)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Requests.Add(request);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(request);
    }
```

span is getting value from JavaScript

```
<span class="col-md-5" id="selecteddate"></span>
```

and here is my form but I write just one of the inputs here for Shorthand. :

```
 <form role="form" method="post" action="/Tour">
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="FName">First Name:</label>
 <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="form-control" id="FName" placeholder="Enter FirstName" />


 </div>

</form>
```

I want to post value of `span` id="selecteddate" to data base in  column named `Date`

appreciate if any one could tell me how it could be possible or if you have any better way as suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution for this is, add a `hidden html input` to your `<from>`. When you do your submit, you write its value as a copy from your span using javascript.

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="/Tour" onsubmit="prepare()">
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="FName">First Name:</label>
 <input type="text" name="FirstName" class="form-control" id="FName" placeholder="Enter FirstName" />


 </div>
<input type="hidden" name="Date" />
</form>

@section Scripts {
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function prepare() {
        document.getElementsByName("Date")[0].value = document.getElementById("selecteddate").innerHtml;
    }
  </script>
}
```

Comment: Because `getElementsByName` returns an array of found names. We only get the first found name in the array

Comment: @nedaDerakhshesh No. ActionLink is `<a>` html element. It is totally different from `<input>` elements. The link is used to navigate to other pages, while the input is used to submit values to server.